# What is the Microsoft Loopback Adapter used for?

Tags: windows, loopback, interface

Why is Microsoft Loopback interface called `_loopback_` inteface?

[RFC3330](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3330/) states that a loopback interface is an interface with an IP address in the  127.0.0.0/8 address range.

Yet, when I enter the `127.x.x.x` address in Microsoft Loopback TCP/IP settings, Windows returns an error.

What is its purpose?

Comment: I've asked the question because I'm confused what the 'loopback' word actually means. As I understand from the sysadmin1138 s response, the word has many meanings depending on the context the word is used in. I.e. I haven't thought about the IPX protocol.

Comment: Fair enough. I have update the question to make it less.. ranty

Comment: Loopback adapter?  http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/tools/6c20/. You cannot assign any IP addresses to that.

Comment: One example of real-world use of the Microsoft Loopback Adapter is to establish a virtual network between a virtual machine and the host, without allowing the virtual machine access to the physical network.

Comment: You're confusing loopback interface with loopback address. They both do similar things, but are not the same thing, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Microsoft is treating it like a loopback *physical interface*. On `_loopback_` you can assign any protocol stack Windows works with, including IPX (up to certain Windows versions) which isn't a TCP/IP protocol at all. The TCP/IP concept of a `loopback interfacce` is a logical concept, and 127.0.0.0/8 addresses apply to the local machine entirely; I don't believe you can explicitly bind them on any Windows adapter.

Comment: Just to add to this, the analogous in Linux is the "lo" interface.